# What happened to SetAttemptedValue in ASP.NET MVC RC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't know what to use in place of it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it has been replaced with SetModelValue.  The source code for RC1 is up at http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx

Comment: Note also that the signature changed.  If you are looking for a ValueProviderResult to pass in as an argument, you can get one from the dictionary provided on Controller.ValueProvider or ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider.  These dictionaries contain values from the form, query string, and route.